# EventMachine - how can you tell if you're falling behind?

Tags: ruby, twitter, eventmachine

I'm looking into using the EventMachine powered twitter-stream rubygem to track and capture tweets. I'm kind of new to the whole evented programming thing. How can I tell if whatever processing I'm doing in my event loop is causing me to fall behind? Is there an easy way to check?

Comment: It would really help if you'd supply a condensed sample of your code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EventMachine has a `EventMachine::Queue.size` method that lets you peek at the current queue and get an idea how big it is.

You could `add_periodic_timer()` and, in that event, get the size of the queue and print it.

If the number is not getting smaller you are at parity. If it's going up you are falling behind.

Comment: It looks like size isn't a class method so you can't call it as written here? `EventMachine::Queue.size`  Is this only for custom queues (an instance of that class), or can it be used to get the queue size of the main reactor?  I'm sort of new to EventMachine so thanks for the help.

Comment: This method is for custom queues not the main reactor queue. In fact there is not a way to get the exact count see (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/eventmachine/7CAkYGZnwzk). Getting the latency is often a good alternative see dj2's answer

Answer (score 8):

You can determine the latency by using a periodic timer and printing out the elapsed time. If you're using a timer of 1 second you should have about 1 second elapsed, if it's greater you know how much you're slowing down the reactor.

```
@last = Time.now.to_f
EM.add_periodic_timer(1) do
  puts "LATENCY: #{Time.now.to_f - @last}"
  @last = Time.now.to_f
end
```