# How can I monitor an EventMachine process?

Tags: eventmachine, newrelic

We're using EventMachine to listen and process to inbound I/O events and we're running into a strange problem where at some point our event loop gets wedged completely where it stops responding, after some amount of time. We are new to EventMachine and have bits of synchronous code in the event loop which isn't great, but I wouldn't expect it to completely grind to a halt under light load. We've not been able to reproduce the issue consistently which makes it really hard to pin it down.

I'd love to monitor the latency inside the loop better. [This Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911405/459863) suggests hooking up a periodic timer which I've done and this seems to work well so far.

```
def self.monitor_reactor_backup
  @last = Time.now
  EM.add_periodic_timer(0.1) do
    latency_ms = (Time.now - @last - 0.1) * 1000
    if latency_ms > 2
      # ::NewRelic::Agent.record_metric('Custom/EM/event_loop_latency', latency_ms)
      msg = "REACTOR BACK-UP >2ms MELTDOWN IMMINENT: #{latency_ms.round} ms"
      Rails.logger.error msg
      puts msg if CONSOLE_MODE
    end
    @last = Time.now
  end
end
```

I've experimented with adding a [NewRelic Custom Metric](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-custom-metric-collection#example_nonmethod) to this, but I can't seem to get the events. I've read in [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187551/is-it-possible-to-monitor-an-eventmachine-process-with-newrelic) that New Relic can be forced to start, but also that it's not supported. What can I do? It also brings up the larger question what the best practices are around monitoring EM processes and knowing when they become under-provisioned?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've pretty much ran in to exactly the same problem.

Comment: We used method above to monitor reactor backup and piped it to a New Relic custom dashboard. What helped a lot was being more aware of all the different ways EventMachine loops can go awry.